# MVP. Взаимодействие Room с presenter (LiveData)

Tags: android, mvp, room, livedata

подскажите пожалуйста как выстроить схему взаимодействия Presenter и Room.
Не понимаю как переделать паттерн MVVM на MVP:
В паттерне MVVM в классе ViewModel мы обращаемся к БД через дао, получаем данные и устанавливаем их Вьюхам:

```
public class MainViewModel extends AndroidViewModel{
private static NotesDatabase database;
private LiveData<List<Note>> notes;

public MainViewModel(@NonNull Application application){
    super(application);
    database = NotesDatabase.getInstance(getApplication()); 
    notes = database.notesDao().getAllNotes();
}

public LiveData<List<Note>> getNotes(){
    return notes;
}

public void insertNote(Note note){
    new InsertTask.execute(note);
} ....и тд
```

1. Теперь чтобы сделать тоже самое с паттерном MVP, я создаю презентер, а где писать логику которая у нас была во ViewModel в MVVM? В самом презентере? Т.е. я просто переношу весь код обращения к бд из ViewModel к презентеру?
2. Во ViewModel в конструкторе мы инициализируем БД и в параметрах получаем Application, потом в  активности в onCreate прописываем следующее:

```
viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ViewModel.class); 
viewModel.getData().observe(this, new Observer<List<Note>>(){
    @Override
    public void onChanged(@Nullable List<Note> note){
        adapter.setNote(note);
      }
    });
```

Как и где в случае с презентером сделать данную реализацию? так же в активности?

Comment: По первому вопросу ответ да, все чем занимался VM, теперь будет заниматься P, с тем лишь отличием, что VM может поставлять данные во множество V понятия не имея кто они, в случае MVP связь V-P обычно однозначная.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В ответ на второй вопрос могу посоветовать воспользоваться библиотекой **Moxy** (https://github.com/Arello-Mobile/Moxy). Она очень удобно позволяет работать с **презентером** при проектировании на паттерне **MVP**, а также автоматически сохраняет состояние вашей активити/фрагмента. На ютубе есть несколько видео обучающих для данной библиотеки. Лично я, когда переписывал свой проект с MVVM на MVP, воспользовался этой библиотекой и этим видео https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OHzTBEBYNAM&t=2645s и все удачно получилось. Удачи!

Comment: я использую эту библиотеку, но возник вопрос как к прикрутить БД к презентеру, не могу никак разобраться. С ViewModel есть уроки, с MVP какие-то сложности

Comment: в репозитории создайте публичный экземпляр dao, и далее в презентере используйте val myDao = repository.dao для инициализации вашего dao

Comment: А строчка:                                                                                                                                  database = NotesDatabase.getInstance(getApplication()); будет указываться в конструкторе презентера?

Comment: Вы можете прямо в конструкторе прописать dao = NotesDatabase.getInstance(getApplication()).getDao. Но я делал через Dependency injection, с помощью Hilt, эта библиотека используется для инъекции зависимостей при построении приложения на чистой архитектуре. А вообще если вам это не нужно, то думаю да, можете прямо в конструкторе проинициализировать ваш Dao